# Why can Normal types still damage Haunter?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the [Pokémon effectiveness chart](http://pokemondb.net/type), it says normal types have no effectiveness against ghost types. Since Haunter is a primarily Ghost type (aside from being Poison type), it should receive no damage from Normal types right?

I'm asking this because I thought I was sneaky with my 450 CP Haunter battling a 1400 CP Snorlax... It did not turn out so well...

Follow-up question, if the answer is that "because Haunter is also a Poison type", are there any Pokémon in Go that are immune to any other pokémon's attacks?

Comment: there are no immunities, only not very effectives